# use groupby and custom agg in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe :

```
id start end
1  1     2
1  13    27
1  30    35
1  36    40
2  2     5
2  8     10
2  25    30
```

I want to groupby over id and aggregate rows where difference of `end` of n-1 row and `start` of n row is less than 10 for example. I already find a way using a loop but it's far too long with over a million rows.

So the expected outcome would be :

```
id start end
1  1     2
1  13    40
2  2     10
2  25    30
```

First I can get the required difference by using `df['diff']=df['start'].shift(-1)-df['end']`. How can I gather ids based on the condition for each different id ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can create groups by suntract shifted `end` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with greater like `10` and cumulative sum and pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
g = df['start'].sub(df.groupby('id')['end'].shift()).gt(10).cumsum()
   
df = (df.groupby(['id',g])
        .agg({'start':'first', 'end': 'last'})
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   id  start  end
0   1      1    2
1   1     13   40
2   2      2   10
3   2     25   30
```

Comment: It's working great ! Thanks ! By any chance, do you know where I can find some documents explaining basics function with examples of pandas like agg, groupby etc. ?

Comment: @Pi-R - I think you can check [tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/tutorials.html)